# In Power BI, is there a view or other way to show a single record as a list of key value pairs?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI, is there a view or other way to show a single record as a list of key value pairs?

I'd like to list out the values of single record/row. Its column headings would be in the first column and the values in the second column. In Azure Log Analytics, this is a default feature with every individual row able to be pivoted. In Powershell, I would pipe the object to Format-List, rather than Format-Table.

Best I can tell from the documentation, the expected solution would be to use single cards. However, there are 40 columns like this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 ColumnN
ValueA1 ValueA2 ValueA3 ValueAN
ValueB1 ValueB2 ValueB3 ValueBN
...
```

That need to be displayed like this, when filtered for record #1:

```
Column1 ValueA1
Column2 ValueA2
Column3 ValueA3
ColumnN ValueAN
...
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are after is to unpivot your table. Do this in Power Query - there are plenty of resources on this online.

If you have a table like this:

| ID | Key 1 | Key 2 | Other cols ++ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | ... |
| 2 | C | D | ... |

You can transform these key columns into a new table using the unpivoting technique. The new table will look like this:

| ID | Attr | Val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Key 1 | A |
| 1 | Key 2 | B |
| 2 | Key 1 | C |
| 2 | Key 2 | D |

And you can use this as a sort of fact table to your original (dimension) table.

The steps involved are as follows:

1. In Power Query, add a new query referencing the original table
2. Remove any columns you do not want to unpivot or retain in the table
3. Select your primary table key (and other columns you want to retain as unpivoted - for whatever reason), and select "unpivot other columns"
4. Load the new table to your model and establish a relationship between the original table and new table on the primary key column.

To utilize this, you can for example create a details table page and add the original table primary column as a drill-through filter. Whenever you want to drill through to the details page with a certain selection, make sure the original primary column is used in the visual.

Comment: See link here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

Comment: Thanks. That looks like the thing. I will try it Monday.

Comment: That link, with much experimentation and several other unmentioned steps, was the answer. I'll give you the credit if you would like to adjust your answer to say; create a table referencing the original, unpivot every column except the primary key, link the two tables on their primary keys, create a details table page adding the original primary key as the drill through filter, add the original table's primary key anywhere expected to drill through from. Otherwise, I will start an all-inclusive answer. Also, will try to make the question more generic.

Comment: I have edited my answer, let me know if that is OK!